# Using existentials to lift values to types without hurting performance

Tags: performance, haskell, dependent-type, existential-type

I'm trying to do composable folds over a sequence (akin to the foldl library), but with more stuff done at type level in the hopes that the compiler will have easier time inlining and CSE'ing things away (and these hopes are not unfounded based on some experiments).

For this I have a type class along the lines of (this is a really simplified example):

```
class Statistic a where
  type StateOf a = k | k -> a
  type ResultOf a = k | k -> a
  extract :: StateOf a -> ResultOf a
  computeStep :: StateOf a -> Double -> StateOf a
  ...
```

I also have a few base instances

```
data Stats = Min | Max | Avg | Stddev

instance Statistic 'Min where ...
instance Statistic 'Max where ...
...
```

as well as a combining instance

```
data a ::: b = a ::: b

instance (Statistic a, Statistic b) => Statistic (a '::: b) where
  type StateOf (a '::: b) = StateOf a ::: StateOf b
  type ResultOf (a '::: b) = ResultOf a ::: ResultOf b
  extract (a ::: b) = extract a ::: extract b
  computeStep = ...
```

and something that actually gets the job done:

```
run :: Statistic s => [Double] -> ResultOf s
run = ...
```

If I do something like `run @('Avg '::: 'Stddev)`, the resulting code performance is about the same as for a hand-written analog, so it looks promising (and it also looks better than foldl, justifying the efforts — it actually looks like `run @('Stddev '::: 'Stddev)` is just as fast as a single stddev!).

But what if I want to write a command-line application and allow the user to select the stats they want to compute? I'll need to translate terms (parsed options) into a type (an instance of `Statistic`)!

This is not that difficult, and this code does the job (and I really love that ghc allows type annotations in patterns):

```
data SomeStats where
  MkSomeStats :: (Statistic s, Show (ResultOf s)) => proxy s -> SomeStats

run' :: SomeStats -> [Double] -> String
run' (MkSomeStats (_ :: proxy s)) input = show $ run @s input

promoteStat :: Stats -> SomeStats
promoteStat Min = MkSomeStats (Proxy :: Proxy 'Min)
promoteStat Max = MkSomeStats (Proxy :: Proxy 'Max)
...

promoteStats :: [Stats] -> SomeStats  -- uh oh, I should've used NonEmpty
promoteStats [s] = promoteStat s
promoteStats (s:ss) =
  case (promoteStat s, promoteStats ss) of
       (MkSomeStats (_ :: proxy1 s), MkSomeStats (_ :: proxy2 ss)) -> MkSomeStats (Proxy :: Proxy (s '::: ss))
```

The result even works correctly, but the performance of the resulting code is awful, an order or two of magnitude worse than the variant with a direct type application without any existentials. This actually makes sense — now the compiler has no chance of inlining things, and it just has to carry the dictionary for the `Statistic` class around, even for the combining instances of `Statistic`!

At this point I'm actually thinking about generating an options handler using Template Haskell that will just generate `2^|Stats| - 1` `case` branches, but it looks inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you measuring the performance? What level of optimization are you using?

Comment: I'm having a simple `main` that `mmap`s a file and runs the statistics computation. I'm doing that over a large enough input that it takes about 1s to run for the "fast" version, and it's in tmpfs to avoid actual IO. I'm building with `-fllvm -O2` (both flags are proven to benefit the fast version).